# PHP Associated Sub Array

Tags: php, mysql

My array look like below how can I display the value of the message and any of the keys.

```
(
   [@@warning_count] => 2

    [0] => Array
    (
      [Level] => Warning
      [Code] => 1366
      [Message] => Incorrect integer value: ‘Johny’ for column ‘billing_cycle’ at row 1
    )

   [1] => Array
   (
     [Level] => Error
     [Code] => 1062
     [Message] => Duplicate entry ‘peace′ for key ‘groupname’
    )

)
```

Comment: What did you try?, it seems your homework....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code....

```
<?php

$my_array = array   ('@@warning_count' => 2,
            0 => Array  (
              'Level' => 'Warning',
              'Code' => '1366',
              'Message' => 'Incorrect integer value: ‘Johny’ for column ‘billing_cycle’ at row 1',
            ),
         1 => Array(
             'Level' => 'Error',
             'Code' => '1062',
             'Message' => 'Duplicate entry ‘peace′ for key ‘groupname’',
            ),
);


foreach ($my_array as $arr_key => $arr_val){

    if(is_array($arr_val) == true ){
        echo $arr_val['Message'];
    }
}

?>
```

Let me know about above code...

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($arr as $val) {
    echo $val['Level'] . "\n";
    echo $val['Code'] . "\n";
    echo $val['Message'] . "\n";
}
```

or

```
foreach($arr as $val) {
    for($val as $innerKey => $innerValue) {
        echo $innerKey . ' == ' . $innerValue . "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the result you want to achieve?

```
<?php
    $dataArray = Array(
        array(
            'Level' => 'Warning',
            'Code' => '1366',
            'Message' => 'Message here 1',
            ),

            array(
            'Level' => 'Warning',
            'Code' => '1062',
            'Message' => 'Message here 2',
            ),

            array(
            'Level' => 'Warning',
            'Code' => '3233',
            'Message' => 'Message here 3',
            )

    );

    // This shows the whole array: 
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($dataArray);
    echo '</pre>';


    // Select only the messages: 
    foreach ($dataArray as $key => $value) {
        echo $value['Message'].'<br />';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response from every one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this. Reference [the working code](http://3v4l.org/lPSXQ):

```
<?php
$myArray = array(
      '@@warning_count' => 2,
      array(
          'level' => 'Warning',
          'code' => 1266,
          'message' => "Incorrect integer value: ‘Johny’ for column ‘billing_cycle’ at row 1"),
      array(
          'level' => 'Warning',
          'code' => 1266,
          'message' => "Incorrect integer value: ‘Johny’ for column ‘billing_cycle’ at row 1"),
);

print "Warning Count: {$myArray['@@warning_count']}\n";
print "------------------\n\n";
foreach ($myArray as $key => $value){
    if (is_array($value)){
        foreach ($value as $subKey => $subValue){
            print $subKey . "=>" . $subValue . "\n";
        }
        print "------------------\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Bubba This works and helps my understanding of dealing with array